# CSS vertical alignment table method has no effect

Tags: html, css

I need to vertically align a box with CSS without using `display: inline-block`. As I don't know the height of my elements I used the way [here](http://vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/) described (CSS Table Method).

```
<div style="background-color: black">
    <div style="background-color: aqua; display: table; margin: auto;">
        <div style="background-color: aliceblue; width: 200px; float: left; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
            <p>A</p>
            <p>A</p>
            <p>A</p>
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: green; height: 20px; width: 100px; float: left; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;"></div>
        <div style="background-color: aliceblue; width: 250px; float: left; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
            <p>B</p>
            <p>B</p>
            <p>B</p>
            <p>B</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, the vertical alignment on this test page has no effect at all. According to the computed CSS of these divs the display value is set to block! How can I make these divs appear in the middle?

Comment: try to erase the float:left from the DIVs - display:table-cell and float:left together makes no sense - see my respective answer below with codepen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

erase the `float:left` from the DIVs - `display:table-cell` and `float:left` together makes no sense

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ORrNdW

ADDITION AFTER COMMENT:

Like this: codepen.io/anon/pen/NRxALO ? 
I inserted /nested another DIV in each table-cell that contains the smaller elements, and assigned the background-color to the table element itself.

Comment: But this way the height value of the elements is ignored - they all have the same height. However, it should look like [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZpQOQw) without the fixed margin.

Answer (score 0):

One way, out of many ways, you can achieve this is by setting the parent to `position:relative;` and its child to `position:absolute; top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%);`. Although this question has been answered many many times before.

Comment: I don't get the example to work with your style. I think you have to set a fixed height. It should look like [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZpQOQw) but without fixed margins or a fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally found the answer. You have to use the flexbox styling (display: flex). Using this method, you can center elements without specifing a height. [This](http://jonibologna.com/flexbox-cheatsheet/) page describes how to use it.